# Как убить процесс Popen('start', shell=True)

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

Привет!
Создаю процесс в питоне

```
p = subprocess.Popen('start', shell=True)
```

Но вот убить его из кода не получается. Перепробовал несколько вариантов, но консоль не закрывается

```
#1
p.kill()
#2
subprocess.Popen("TASKKILL /F /PID {pid} /T".format(pid=p.pid))
#3
p.terminate()
```

Comment: именно так, windows

Comment: Используя `shell=True` - возвращается pid оболочки, а не самого процесса, так что вариант, который может сработать - `os.killpg`

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov: сигналы на Windows весьма ограничены. `os.killpg` не поддерживается (можно попробовать послать процессам из той же консоли сигнал (`start` новое окно открывает): `os.kill(pid,  signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)` (не тестировал)), хотя если [taskkill не помогает](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17614872/4279), то нужно больше подробностей.

Answer (score 2):

Методы `.terminate()`, `.kill()` у `subprocess.Popen` пытаются остановить только сам процесс:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys
import time

start = time.monotonic()
process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable or 'python', '-c',
                            'import time; time.sleep(30)'])
assert process.poll() is None  # process is alive
process.terminate()
process.wait()
assert (time.monotonic() - start) < 30  # exited before timeout
assert process.poll() is not None  # process is dead and reaped
```

При этом дочерние процессы могут продолжать жить, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36952245/4279).

Вызвав `Popen()` с `shell=True` параметром, создаётся неявно процесс (`cmd.exe`, `/bin/sh`), который запускает переданную команду. Если это не встроенная/внутренняя команда, то у вас как минимум два процесса получается (сама оболочка плюс программа, которую она запустила). `.kill()` убивает саму оболочку, при этом дочерний процесс может продолжить жить. На *nix в этом случае можно попробовать запускать процесс в отдельной группе процессов и затем послать сигнал этой группе, чтобы все процессы завершились (похоже на то как <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> в баше работает): [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279). На Windows, [можно taskkill попробовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17614872/4279):

```
from subprocess import Popen, check_call

process = Popen('py -c "import time; time.sleep(30)"', shell=True)
check_call("TASKKILL /F /PID {pid} /T".format(pid=process.pid))
```

`/T` аргумент говорит, что taskkill пытается убить как сам процесс так и любые дочерние процессы, которые он запустил. Используя `/IM` параметр, можно по имени процессы остановить.

`psutil` модуль предоставляет [переносимый способ убить дочерние процессы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229404/4279).

Чтобы закрыть новое окно, созданное `start` командой, по завершению дочерней команды, можно явно `/c` параметр передать для `cmd`:

```
D:\> start /wait "title" cmd /c batch.cmd
```

Можно добавить `/B` к `start`, чтобы не создавалось новое окно. Если вы использовали start, чтобы в фоне, что-то выполнить, то в Питоне этого не нужно, просто уберите `start` (`Popen()` вызов не ждёт пока процесс завершится). Аналогично, если вам не нужно [внутреннюю команду](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) запустить, то можно без `shell=True` обойтись как правило.

В качестве альтернативы явной остановки, можно запустить процессы таким образом, чтобы дочерние процессы автоматически уничтожались, когда родитель завершается: [Python: how to kill child process(es) when parent dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23434842/4279) На Windows, это можно организовать [присваиванием созданного родительского процесса к своему Job объекту](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942797/4279).

Answer (score 0):

```
def killprocess():
    ppidd = # любым способом получаем pid нужного нам процесса
    if ppidd:
        try:
            p = psutil.Process(ppidd)
            p.terminate()
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            print ('oops loose process')
```

Comment: не помогло, окно не закрылось

Comment: может код покажете?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что `start` запускает процесс, который открывает окно и завершается, поэтому "убивать" возвращенный pid бессмысленно. Предлагаю 3 варианта:

1. пробежаться по всем процессам с помощью psutil и найти, у какого был родителем указанный pid.
2. запустить `start "MySpecWindoe"`, а потом каким-то способом (каким, не пробовал) найти консоль с таким заголовком.
3. у меня сработал такой код, запускал `start C:\Python35\python.exe abc.py`, может это решит задачу:

   ```
   import time
   import subprocess


   p = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')

   time.sleep(5)

   p.kill()
   ```

Comment: Какие-то варианты все костыльные...