# Как закрыть процесс на python

Tags: python, subprocess

Я открываю сайт в гугл (режим инкогнито) через `subprocess.Popen`. Когда `time.sleep(5)` завершился, функция `process.terminate()` или `process.kill()` не закрывает гугл.

Мой код:

```
import requests
import subprocess
import time
while True:
  try:
    responce = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_url')
    try:
        if responce.json()['WARNING']:
          print('All complete')
          time.sleep(5)
    except:
      url = responce.json()['messages']
      p = subprocess.Popen([f"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "-incognito",url])
      # os.system(f"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -ArgumentList @( '-incognito', 'www.google.com'" )
      time.sleep(5)
      p.terminate()
      p.kill()
      print(url)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Ссылки по теме: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/716789/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-popenstart-shell-true), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971393/python-subprocess-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81)

Comment: И ещё [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552815/open-chrome-from-command-line-and-wait-till-its-closed) как раз про Chrome.

Comment: Неа, выводит либо гугл не может считать профиль, либо �訡��: �� 㤠���� ���� ����� "2936"